# Error in RemoteConnect.Connect() err=WNetAddConnection2 returned: 1203 

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, path

This is an ASP.NET, C# application. I am trying to save a file on a server, but I am getting below error:

> Error in RemoteConnect.Connect() err=WNetAddConnection2 returned: 1203 msg=No network provider accepted the given network path.

Here now I am trying to save on my local machine, path I am using is C:\Docs 
but I am getting the above error.

Please any help would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer finally, the path I gave was local machine path but I need to give a Network path which will be like this "@\ComputerName\FolderName"